# what does arrow and diamond symbol in class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have the below UML generated via tool for the classes i have been using. Can any one elaborate when the dotted line is being generated and what does it means the line followed by diamond and an arrow with number "1" on side indicates.

Sample UML for my class is attached, to make it simple i made one dummy class diagram.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dotted arrow is a dependency.

Filled diamond represents composition. The number is the amount of composed items.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Relationships